# Pass/bind data objects to inner/embedded Symfony2 forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

i have the following form where i would like to pass some objects to the inner forms in order to populate them with data when being edited:

```
        public function __construct( $em, $id )
        {
            $this->_em = $em;
        }

        public function buildForm( \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
        {        
            $builder->add( 'accessInfo', new AccessInfoType( $this->_em, $options[ 'entities' ][ 'user' ] ) , array(
                                                                'attr'  => array( 'class' => 'input-medium' ),
                                                                'required'      => false,
                                                                'label'         => false
                                                             )
            );
            $builder->add( 'profileInfo', new ProfileInfoType( $this->_em, $options[ 'entities' ][ 'profile' ] ) , array(
                                                                'required'      => false,
                                                                'label'         => false
                                                             )
            );
        }

        public function setDefaultOptions( \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface $resolver )
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults( $this->getDefaultOptions( array() ) );
            return $resolver->setDefaults( array( ) );
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public function getDefaultOptions( array $options )
        {
            $options = parent::getDefaultOptions( $options );
            $options[ 'entities' ]   = array();

            return $options;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'UserType';
        }
```

which i instantiate with the following code:

```
$form = $this->createForm( new UserType( $em ), null, array( 'entities' => array( 'user' => $userObj, 'profile' => $profileObj ) ) );
```

Once i get, via the constructor, the object containing the needed data does anyone know how could i bind that object to the form?

```
class ProfileInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    private $_em;

    public function __construct( $em, $dataObj )
    {
        $this->_em = $em;
        $this->_dataObj = $dataObj;
    }
```

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and fixed this with `inherit_data`

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'inherit_data' => true,
    ));
}
```

See also http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller yo should get the request data

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
```

or request it through the method parameters

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
```

and then bind it to the form

```
$form->bind($request);
```

For further details have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Comment: Thanks Michi, maybe i missexplained or you didn't understand the question correctly. I'm trying to bind an object to an inner/embedded form in order to let Symfony2 populate the form at template printing time.

Comment: @user846226 I think I don't really understand... could you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve... you might be talking about collections (http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: Hi Michi, no i'm not talking about collections. I've created a parent form type which embeds other child form types, as i want Symfony2 to populate those nested forms with data i'm looking for a way to pass the data to child forms, which right now i'm doing via constructor. Once the child gets the object to populate the form with i need to make some kind of call to get the form populated. Right now i'm trying to accomplish it via closure http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/use_empty_data.html

Answer (score 0):

this works well add an attr for use the html attribute 'value' depends of the form type, maybe this can help you.

Twig

```
{{ form_label(blogpostform.title) }}
{{ form_widget(blogpostform.title, {'attr': {'value': titleView }}) }}
{{ form_errors(blogpostform.title) }}
```